# How to open chrome app with specific URL through chrome_proxy.exe?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, command-line-interface

I have a Chrome app that I created with "Create Application Shortcut".
What I need is to open that app with specific url on the same domain.

Example:

```
chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=xxxxxxxx "https://www.google.com"
```

Is that possible or any command that achive the same result?

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing you installed the Chrome app so that the website launches in a standalone window. If this is the case, you can achieve something similar by using the `--app` command line switch instead.

Eg: `chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app="https://www.google.com"`

This doesn't strictly open the URL in the existing app, but it does open that specific URL in a standalone window.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working with `--app="https://www.google.com"`, but just the URL (without `--app`) worked great. This is a good way to get Chrome to open a site in a regular browser tab rather than a PWA app window.

Answer (score 12):

Using this will work:

```
chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=xxxxxxxx --app-launch-url-for-shortcuts-menu-item="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
```

**It will launch in the special standalone window AND navigate to the specified URL.**

Replace *xxxxxxxx* with the app id (this can be found if you look at the properties of the shortcut it created), but after you create the app this part should already be filled in.

At that point all you need to add is this part:

```
--app-launch-url-for-shortcuts-menu-item="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
```

Replacing the *https:​//youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ* part with the full URL of where you would like to navigate to.

[Documentation of the argument can be found here.](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#app-launch-url-for-shortcuts-menu-item)

*Credit due in part to [김보근's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73266841/4848067).*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33460408)

Comment: How does it not answer the question? I literally provided a correct answer and solution for the what the asker asked. And I provided more information than the other answer, with documentation links.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer what you are looking for.

```
chrome_proxy.exe --profile-directory=Default --app-id=xxxxxxxx --app-launch-url-for-shortcuts-menu-item="https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
```